# Correct tag for one line of text?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

What's the correct HTML markup for a single line of text?

The text is not a title so I've ruled out h1, etc. The text is not part of copy so I've ruled out p. The text is just an instruction to the user, click below for more info.

What's the correct tag to use?

Comment: It's a single-line paragraph, using `<p>` is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

`<span>` is usually the go-to for everything not containers or headings. They typically display inline on default, so they won't break text line endings.

Comment: Incorrect information. Span should be specifically used for styling.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `<p>` tag in this instance. You may also consider putting in a `span` to make the tag semantic like:

```
<p><span class="user-directive">click below for more info</span></p>
```

You can also use the span tag in isolation but that isn't necessarily always going to work as you'd expect.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question so clear.
But, if what you're trying to do is "Click this sentence to see more info" `<span>` should work well.

http://jsbin.com/xeqaqu/1/edit?output